# Delete from Mysql (android)

Tags: php, android, mysql

so yesterday it was working fine , all i did today was change the url cause my ip address changes , i dont know what's wrong with it , it says * deleted perfectly* but it actually doesn't delete a thing 
here's my php script

```
       <?php
       $servername = "localhost";
       $username = "root";
       $password = "";
       $dbname = "restaurant";

       // Create connection
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      // Check connection
       if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    //$_POST["sIDCOMMANDES"]=6;

   $commandesID = $_POST["sIDCOMMANDES"];
    $strSQL = "DELETE FROM commandes WHERE 1 AND ID_COMMANDES = '".$commandesID."'   ";
      $result = $conn->query($strSQL);
      if(!$result)
      {
     $ar["StatusID"] = "0";
     $ar["Error"] = "Cannot delete data!";
      }
    else
       {
   $ar["StatusID"] = "1";
      $ar["Error"] = "";

        }

      print(json_encode($ar));
     $conn->close();
       ?>
```

I ve tested it and it s working fine , now here s my code for deleting a row from my listview

```
               public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;



    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.get_all_comm_list_view, null);

    }

    ImageButton cmdDelete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
    cmdDelete.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    final AlertDialog.Builder adb1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Comm.this);

    final AlertDialog.Builder adb2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Comm.this);

    cmdDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            adb1.setTitle("Delete?");

            adb1.setMessage("Are you sure delete [" + MyArrList.get(position).get("NOM_PLAT") +"]");

            adb1.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

            adb1.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    String url = "http://192.168.1.7/deleteData.php";

                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sIDCOMMANDES", MyArrList.get(position).get("ID_COMMANDES")));
                    String resultServer  = getJSONUrll(url, params);


                    String strStatusID = "0";

                    String strError = "Unknown Status";

                    try {

                        JSONObject c = new JSONObject(resultServer);

                        strStatusID = c.getString("StatusID");

                        strError = c.getString("Error");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if(strStatusID.equals("0"))

                    {

                        adb2.setTitle("Error! ");
                        adb2.setPositiveButton("Close", null);
                        adb2.setMessage(strError);

                        adb2.show();

                    }

                    else

                    {

                        Toast.makeText(Comm.this, "Delete data successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ShowData(); // reload data again

                    }

                }});

            adb1.show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: nothing s changed , yesterday i had written  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("commandesID", MyArrList.get(position).get("ID_COMMANDES"))) instead of sIDCOMMANDES , but now if i wanna do it it says  Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: here it is i ve limited it

Comment: so java is calling `http://192.168.1.7/deleteData.php` on the local subnet, and that IP address is new, not new, what

Comment: hum okay, well thanks for your help .

Comment: i don't think it's a problem with the ip address , since the other connections i'm using for other scripts i have in my application are working fine.

Comment: look at the inards of the call to delete. it can return a false positive. the parameters.

Comment: i'm sorry , what? i didn't quite get what you're saying

Comment: on the php side you can 1) log access requests, 2) the delete.php routine can open for append and dump out to a txt file each request it receives at the top of it .... there are many ways to debug otherwise seemingly blind server-side routines

Comment: yeah basically jam any parameters that the php side gets, log to a txt file opened in append mode til you resolve it

Comment: Try call PHP script in browser. PHP script says some error report if answer starts with <br.